# How to create basic plain test report in Cypress

Tags: html, cypress, test-reporting, mochawesome

I need help with connecting an additional reporter to Cypress tests.
I am looking for a basic, really plain (HTML) report with only names of tests and statuses (Fail/Pass). Later I will send it via email.

I found [Mochawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome), but this is too complicated for a one-page email. Do you have any ideas what I can use?

It would be ideal to have the results in a table like below. However, the most important thing is that this view should be simple and can be sent by e-mail

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own script inside `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e": "cypress run --headless --browser chrome > Newt-e2e-test-results.txt",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
},
```

You can call `e2e` script with `npm run e2e`. That script will simply run in the headless mode and then output the results.

Text output will be something like the below image.

[image]